# External monitor as primary for MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook, external-display

Is there any way to make my external LCD connected to MacBook Pro as primary? So the top menu and task bar will operate on external rather than built in one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to keep the lid open but use the external monitor as the primary display, go to the Displays pane in System Preferences, click on Arrangement, and drag the white rectangle from one screen to the other.

Otherwise, see this article, [Using an external display with a MacBook](http://www.livingdigitally.net/2006/10/using_an_extern.html), which says:

> When your laptop is open, you can't
>   switch to using the full resolution of
>   an external monitor. I have no idea
>   why, but it's a fact of life for
>   MacBook users. You can use both
>   displays in "extended" mode, or you
>   can mirror your MacBook's display
>   (which most likely doesn't use the
>   full resolution of your external
>   monitor), but you can't switch to
>   using only the external monitor. Very
>   strange.
>
> If you close your laptop, you can
>   actually get the full resolution of
>   your external display. Put your
>   MacBook to sleep, connect your
>   external display and an external
>   monitor, and wake the computer up by
>   pressing any key. You will have full
>   use of your external display while
>   your laptop is closed.
>
> If you really want to have your
>   MacBook open while only using an
>   external display, after following the
>   procedure above, you can open your
>   MacBook, and its screen will remain
>   off, which means you can still use the
>   MacBook's keyboard and trackpad. Why
>   you can't get into this mode using F7,
>   I have no idea. This is a good
>   technique for allowing some heat to
>   dissipate while still using an
>   external display so the lid of your
>   MacBook doesn't melt or warp.

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Insomnia](http://semaja2.net/insomniaxinfo).

> It always has been a missing feature: disabling the sleep mode on a Apple Laptop. Who does not want to use it as a big juke-box or go warwalking. The best looking server ever, especially at about one inch height. This small utility is what you will want, this small utility acts as a wrapper to the Insomnia kernel extension.

(Hoping to suggest a better way for people who find this thread)